# How to export a GLTF with more than one armature? (2.79)

Tags: animation, rigging, gltf

I have been doing some simple testing with 2 meshes parented to 2 different armatures with different materials. Then trying to export them to GLTF2 format and what happens is that whichever armature is on the top of the Outliner is being exported as shown in blender, but the other one is far from that. I am not sure if the current exporter can handle more than one armature in the same scene or whether I am doing something wrong.

Comment: There's been some recent activity on the [glTF issue tracker related to armatures](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+armature).  If you can't find exactly your issue listed there, can you file a new issue with a test blend file please?  Thanks!

Comment: It looks like the [problem is reported](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter/issues/232) since May 2018 and yet not solved. Don't know tho if there is any workaround that could be helpful whilst is being solved.